# Can't run JavaFx code from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx

I found this code on the site oracle but I can't launch with Eclipse it's saying me "Unable to launch". I have installed JDK 8 but it doesn't work...

Anybody have a solution please ? :p

```
public class SwingFX extends Application {

@Override
public void start (Stage stage) {
    final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

    createSwingContent(swingNode);

    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

    stage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 250, 150));
    stage.show();
    }

private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
        }
    });
}
}
```

link to the website where I found the code : https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm

Comment: Dumb questions first: Did it compile without errors?

Comment: Does eclipse show any errors by underlining in red?

Comment: There's no main method!

Comment: @PascalAckermann In Java 8, you don't need a main method.

Comment: @James_D Right but, eclipse does.

Comment: @James_D correction it is not Java 8 but JavaFx application that does not require a main method.

Comment: @Blip Well, both. In Java 8, a  `javafx.application.Application` subclass can be launched without a `main(...)` method. (But this is not true prior to Java 8.)

Comment: @Zaheylu Eclipse can't detect it automatically, but you can actually launch it if you go into "Run Configurations" and set up a run config for it.

Comment: @James_D yes but ordinary Java 8 applications require main method.

Comment: @Blip Isn't that what I just agreed to?

Comment: @James_D I was clarifying what you said and it was not explicitly mentioned in the comments you and I had made prior to my previous comment so that our comments won't mislead any new user of Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 8, you can directly launch a `javafx.application.Application` subclass even if it doesn't have a `main(String[] args)` method. The issue is that the current version of Eclipse doesn't check for this, and (at least in the context menus) only checks whether the `main(...)` method exists. So to allow it to run from Eclipse, you can either add the `main(...)` method yourself:

```
public class SwingFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Or, you can directly instruct Eclipse to run it from the "Run Configurations" wizard. With your `SwingFX` class selected, choose "Run" from the menu, and then "Run Configurations". In the "Main" tab make sure the correct class name appears (i.e. "SwingFX") and then press the "Run" button.

Once you've set this up, the green "Run" button on the toolbar (in the Java perspective) will run the application again, until you run something else.

Comment: I've tried your solution and its works ! Thank you ! :)

Comment: Another trick is to add the main method and invoke the lunch method once and then comment the main method out. After that eclipse is aitomatically set to run the application even without the main method.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a problem detecting that JavaFX applications can be launched without a `main` method in Java 8 - a workaround is to add this yourself

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Or you can go into Run -> Run Configurations and set up a run configuration yourself.

Answer (score -1):

you have not written the main method. thus JVM does not know the starting point